# Cannot reload Asp.Net Core project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Upon removing a bower package (morris) and trying to reload my MVC Core application, I got an error and the application would not reload fully, all I can see are DNX references and `Dependencies`. I tried restoring the packages, but it didn't help.

I am running RC1.

Studio directed me to a `VsProjectFault_9481d3e1-ac32-4ffe-bee5-00ea5d3c38b8.failure.txt` file with the following information:

```
Recoverable
System.Exception: The following error occurred during discovery of project files on disk. Access to the path 'C:\Redacted\App\bower_components\morrisjs\spec\viz\exemplary' is denied..
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.ProjectSystem.ProjectTree.SourceItemsInMemoryProject.<InitializeFromDiskAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.ProjectSystem.ProjectTree.SourceItemsInMemoryProject.<Creator>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.AutoLoadMethodStateMachine.<<StartExecution>b__6_0>d.MoveNext()
```

What do I need to do to recover the application?

All the files are still present on the file system, just not loaded with the project.

Comment: Do you have any bower tasks keeping files locked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing Visual Studio and deleting the hidden `.vs` folder brought the solution back to life.

(Just closing Studio alone was not enough, but I did have other instances of it open so perhaps that is enough.)